# MongoDB how to populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have 2 Schemas. 1. ProjectBug and 2. ProjectBugImage so i am uploading an image and saving it in a different collection.

See the Schemas below Number 1

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let ProjectBugSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    projectID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
    },
    completed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    components: Boolean,
    groupSelect: String,
    appsAffected: Array,
    title:String,
    description:String,
    selectedcomponents: Array,
    resources: Array,
    isLive: Boolean,
    issueNumber: String,
    projectBugMianID: String,
    date: String,
    reporter: String,
    foundOn: String,
    testedDevel: Boolean,
    testedLive: Boolean,
    testedStaging: Boolean,
    platform: String,
    linked: Boolean,
    linkedTo: String,
    type: String,
    appPassword: String,
    appUsername: String,
    percentageComplete: String,
    status: String,
    releaseID: {
      type: String
    },
    createdAt:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },

},{
  timestamps: true
},{
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  });

  ProjectBugSchema.virtual('bugImage', {
    ref: 'bugImage',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'bugID'
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('ProjectBug', ProjectBugSchema);
```

Number 2

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const ProjectBugImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bugID:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  },
  fileName:{
    type: String,
  },
  path: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('bugImage', ProjectBugImageSchema)
```

And then i my controller i have

```
exports.index = (req, res) => {
    ProjectBug.find({})
        .populate('bugImage', '', null, { })
        .exec((err, bugs) => {
            if(err){
                res.send(err)
            }
            res.send(bugs)
        })
}
```

Strange thing is this used to work, and now it does not anymore, as you can see i have the ProjectbugSchema.vertual('bugImage', {...}) with the ref to bugImage and the local field to _id and foreignField to 'bugID' so that would match the ProjectBugImage.bugID with the local field of ProjectBug _id

what i get when i get data. Response

```
 {
        "completed": false,
        "appsAffected": [],
        "selectedcomponents": [],
        "resources": [],
        "_id": "5e8195fcc7939644cc322793",
        "groupSelect": "",
        "title": "asdasd",
        "description": "<p>asdasd</p>",
        "issueNumber": "",
        "date": "2020-03-30",
        "reporter": "5d305d3a9fe62f5578d0e209",
        "type": "bug",
        "foundOn": "",
        "isLive": false,
        "testedDevel": false,
        "testedLive": false,
        "testedStaging": false,
        "platform": "",
        "appUsername": "",
        "appPassword": "",
        "percentageComplete": "",
        "status": "",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-30T06:47:24.751Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-30T06:47:24.751Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

All i want is all the images that has bugID to be with the projectbug where the ids match. and put them into an array. Am i doing something wrong in the populate?? or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi there! The controller that inserts the `bugImage` doc, what does it assigns to the `bugImage.bugID` property? Is it `projectBug._id` or `projectBug. projectID`?

Comment: Hi it assigns the projectbug._id to it so that the projectbug._id and the bugimage.bugID is exactly the same. Both object ids

Comment: bugimage = bugID: ObjectId(5e81c43b311fad4d08b19b24), and the projectBug: _id: ObjectId = ObjectId(5e81c43b311fad4d08b19b24)

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out, in the model where i create the virtual  i had

```
  ,{
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  });
```

I took that out closed the Schema and underneath i put

```
ProjectBugSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })
ProjectBugSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true })
```

Small change but seems to be the answer.

Comment: This could also have been at the place where you put `timestamps: true`! Also as you use the timestamps option you don't need to add the field `createdAt` manually